# How do I set an Win32 system environment variable in Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, environment-variables

I want to be able to set a system environment variable in Perl and I wrote the following script (inspired from [this idea](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/03/18/how-can-i-create-an-environment-variable-using-a-script.aspx)) to accomplish this:

```
use Win32;
use Win32::API;
use Win32::OLE qw( in );

my $machine = ".";
my $WMIServices = Win32::OLE->GetObject ( "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(security)}//$machine/root/cimv2" ) || die;

my $objVariable = $WMIServices->Get("Win32_Environment")->SpawnInstance_;
$objVariable->{Name}="NewOSType";
$objVariable->{UserName} = "<System>";
$objVariable->{VariableValue} = "LAMBDA";
$objVariable->Put_;
```

However, I am not an expert in Perl and I would like to know what the experts think about this code. Is this the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I am not an expert in either Perl or Windows. I recommend (and so will the experts) to `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code. It is considered good practice and will save your time.

Comment: On Unix, you do `$ENV{VARIABLENAME}="chosen value";`.
I don't know of a reason not to do the same on Windows, but it depends in part on what you mean by 'system environment variable'. I suspect you may be trying to tamper with the registry instead.  For that, you will need accurate input from others.

Comment: @Jonathan, By system environment variable, i mean the environment variables you find in the Computer Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables > System. These variables are persisted even after a system restart; However if we do a $ENV{VARIABLENAME}="chosen value", then that variable is only valid for the current session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possible approach:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::TieRegistry qw[:KEY_];
use Win32::API;
use constant HWND_BROADCAST => -1;
use constant WM_SETTINGCHANGE => 0x1a;

my $hklm_env = Win32::TieRegistry->new(
    'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Session Manager/Environment', 
    { Access => KEY_READ() | KEY_WRITE(), Delimiter => '/' }
); # returns undef if SYSTEM ENV not writable

my $hkcu_env = Win32::TieRegistry->new(
    'HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Environment', 
    { Access => KEY_READ() | KEY_WRITE(), Delimiter => '/' }
);

# if SYSTEM ENV not writable try USER ENV
my $e = defined($hklm_env) ? $hklm_env : $hkcu_env;

if(defined $e) {
  $e->SetValue('Variable', 'Value');  
}
else {
  warn "Cannot open neither SYSTEM ENV nor USER ENV registry for Read+Write";
}

my $SendMessage = new Win32::API("user32", "SendMessage", 'NNNP', 'N') or die "Couldn't create SendMessage: $!\n";
my $RetVal = $SendMessage->Call(HWND_BROADCAST,WM_SETTINGCHANGE,0,'Environment');
```

Comment: I think Santhosh's code is better as WMI is the way recommended by Microsoft. Also, it is shorter. Anyway, +1 for the WM_SETTINGCHANGE that would be not known to those tempted by a direct manipulation of the registry.